# Is it possible to get the connection string from appsettings.json file to the Controller?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

If it is possible, how can I use the connection string inside the API (for example Login API)? Please help if there is a solution. Thanks in advance.

I am tried using injection method. But I can not get the connection string inside API call.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.